# Few questions regarding git on the computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

So I've recently got into development using Rails, and therefore slowly introduced myself to git as a version control as well. Just a few things that I'm curious about

I followed this tutorial recently :

http://guides.railsgirls.com/github/

Everything went as smoothly as I wanted. It just raised a few questions.

Now in this tutorial I set my "git remote add origin...." as the repo that I wanted to upload my app to. All well. So I decided to close everything (Terminal, Text editor etc.) And opened up the terminal again and I could very easily push my update just by using

```
git add .
```

followed by

```
git commit -m "Message"
```

and then

```
git push origin master
```

So technically the "remote" address was saved (What do we usually refer to this address as ?)

So what I'm wondering, is this saved for all work done in my CURRENT folder (therefore, this specific app) or, if I cd into another folder and tried to push it would push to the same place?

I'm just trying to understand the workflow of a developer who lets say works on multiple projects. Is the other folder already set to upload to a different remote address, or is the remote address set for the whole PC, and therefore if working on another project he needs to change the address (if so, how is this done?)

Also, if I turned off my PC and switched it back on, would I need to do the whole set up again? (Adding the remote address etc.).

And is there a command to check which remote address the terminal is currently going to upload to if I use the push command etc.?

Thank you

Comment: That's quite a number of questions. You might need to study a git tutorial then look at some [workflow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html) examples. But basically you `git init` a project root folder once then work on a branch (`master`). The remote is usually set per project repository (I have github repos and bitbucket repos) or different per branch. If you cd into a new git repo directory it remembers the working branch for that repo even after you shut off the computer.

Comment: @Jasen Thanks a lot. That workflow example looks really good. Should give it a look. Are you saying for one project you have two repos, One github and bitbucket, and running git push pushes your files to both repos? I can see that being useful! 

Thanks once again!

Comment: I usually only work with a single remote per repo but it is common to have different remotes.

Comment: @Jasen Oh I see, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This info is typically done once per setup, per repo and is saved under `.git/config` in the root of your repo like so

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://user@url/project.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

So unless you delete the directory containing the repo, you won't lose this information. Restarting your computer or navigating different folders *in the same repo* won't change this either. Again, the key here is *per repo*, if your other project is setup as a different repo, it will have a different remote, but you could just as well setup another project or dependency under the same current repo.

To check your remote (that's what it's called) just type

```
git remote -v
origin  ssh://user@url/project.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://user@url/project.git (push)
```

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So technically when I run any git commands, it looks into the .git/config folder. So when I push, it looks at that specific url and pushes it there. So for another folder/project it would be different. Wow that's a nice way to think of it, Think i got that sorted now.

Thanks a lot, Now that I have an idea of how it works, It will be easier to progress further!

Comment: @Kando not any command, specifically ones that interact with the remote like pull/push/fetch etc. Other commands can have additional config elsewhere

Comment: Oh I see. Definitely get it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So technically the "remote" address was saved (What do we usually refer to this address as ?)

**This is the remote address (or one of your remotes).**

So what I'm wondering, is this saved for all work done in my CURRENT folder (therefore, this specific app).

**Yes. Only for the folder that contains the '.git' folder (and all its subfolders)**

or, if I cd into another folder and tried to push it would push to the same place?

**No. Git only monitors folders inside the a folder that contains the '.git' folder.**

I'm just trying to understand the workflow of a developer who lets say works on multiple projects.

**Git is very simple, monitors everything inside a folder! (that is it)**

Is the other folder already set to upload to a different remote address,

**No, you may have many remote addresses. But they aren't assign by folder.
When you push (stage/commit/push), it's not related to folders, it's related to what you stage:** 'git add .' **; or** 'git add [file]' **.**

or is the remote address set for the whole PC,

**No.**

and therefore if working on another project he needs to change the address (if so, how is this done?)

**No.**

Also, if I turned off my PC and switched it back on, would I need to do the whole set up again? (Adding the remote address etc.).

**No.**

And is there a command to check which remote address the terminal is currently going to upload to if I use the push command etc.?

**$ git remote -v**

**It will show the shortname and the URLs that Git has stored for remotes.**

Comment: Thank you SO much. You and the other answer both gave awesome answers (Sadly I can't select two answers as the "accepted answer"

Thanks once again, very insightful.